# Tool Tip is not showing properly when Zoom in & Zoom out on the browser is performed

Tags: extjs, tooltip, extjs3

I am using EXT JS 3.4.

The code of my Column Model goes like this : -
My Ext.grid.Column for Column Model is getting configured from the database like this.

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel( {
            columns : cols // the cols is getting generated from the database
        });
```

The json data for the cols mentioned in above code is generated as follows:

```
{
  header: "Title Alias",
  type: "STRING",
  dataIndex: "order#title_alias",
  width: 80,
  tooltip: "Title Alias",
  sortable: "true",
  filter: {
    test: "/^{0}/i"
  }
}
```

QUERY :  The tool tip is shown in two lines. i want the tool tip to adjust its width 
according to text the tool tip text should be shown in single line only.

BOUNDATION : cannot modify "cols".

APPROACH : can we override or apply some kind of configuration to the quick tips. IS it possible.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to set the css for the tooltip and define:

```
.x-tip .x-tip-body {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

to prevent it from wrapping.